# SPARQL QUERY RDF FILE

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web

I'm newbie in SPARQL,

I have a rdf with the following structure:

```
 <rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:ns2="http://fia.upm.es/ontologies/opendata/smartod/smartod.owl#"
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#" >


<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/1">
 <ns2:CONV_INT rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">0</ns2:CONV_INT>
 <ns3:defaultGeometry rdf:resource="http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/Geometry/d9927de3ace3435ea192ea000b487e8a1db6c9c5" />
 <ns2:CCAA_INENP rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">0</ns2:CCAA_INENP>
 <ns2:DN_OID rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">1.10088e+09</ns2:DN_OID>
 <ns2:INENP rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">0</ns2:INENP>
 <ns2:MAB_CODE rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">0</ns2:MAB_CODE>
 <ns2:Shape_Area rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">101.359</ns2:Shape_Area>
 <ns2:Shape_Leng rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">44.8041</ns2:Shape_Leng>
 <ns3:hasGeometry rdf:resource="http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/Geometry/d4fcb8dd21917066d9ff3945e12c8fab2c62c3af" />
```

...
....

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/Geometry/d4fcb8dd21917066d9ff3945e12c8fab2c62c3af">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#Point" />
  <ns3:asWKT rdf:datatype="http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#wktLiteral">POINT (101456.13051790577 4685032.686725916)</ns3:asWKT>
</rdf:Description>
```

....

Im trying to execute the following query, but it does not return  nothing, can you help me please?

The query:

```
 PREFIX ns2:   <http://fia.upm.es/ontologies/opendata/smartod/smartod.owl#>
 PREFIX ns3:   <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>

SELECT ?geometry_point ?geometry_uri ?uri
WHERE {

 ?uri a <http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/10> .
 ?uri ns3:hasGeometry ?geometry_uri .
 ?geometry_uri ns3:asWKT ?geometry_point
 }
```

Thanks so much

Comment: http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/10 -> http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/1

Comment: but also with this change, <http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/1> is the subject of the statements, not the type. The "a" keyword in SPARQL is a shorthand for rdf:type

Answer (score 2):

The query is wrong, try removing

```
 ?uri a <http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/10> .
```

that is equivalent to:

```
 ?uri rdf:type <http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/10> .
```

Now, if you look at the data:

- there is no rdf:type statement
- the resource http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/1 (or /10? a typo?) is actually the subject of the statements, not 
  the type.

A working query would also be:

```
PREFIX ns2:   <http://fia.upm.es/ontologies/opendata/smartod/smartod.owl#>
PREFIX ns3:   <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>

SELECT ?geometry_point ?geometry_uri 
WHERE {
   <http://fia.upm.es/parcelas/10> ns3:hasGeometry ?geometry_uri .
   ?geometry_uri ns3:asWKT ?geometry_point
}
```

depending on what you want to achieve.